# Aptana terminal background

Tags: colors, terminal, background, aptana

After updating to Windows 10 Pro from Windows 7 Pro, my terminal in Aptana Studio 3.6 is pink and I'm not able to change the color. Could anybody explain how to change the background color of the Aptana terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I only used Aptana in windows 10, evidently the text editor background for themes are being ignored.

I fixed this by going.
Perferences > Editors > Colours and Fonts > Background colour

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately changing the background color of the Editor does not effect the terminal. Maybe I'm in the wrong preferences?